# "Passer du coq à l'âne" : Est-ce courant ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

Peut-on utiliser couramment l'expression "[passer du coq à l'âne](https://lemagdesanimaux.ouest-france.fr/dossier-1042-passer-coq-ane.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CPasser%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0%20l,%C3%A9vident%2C%20sans%20transition%20ni%20liaison.)" lorsque l'on parle d'un sujet puis d'un autre alors que ceux-ci n'ont pas de liens directs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour ma part, je pense avoir plus souvent entendu dire « passer du coq à l'âne ». Cela dit, d'après [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=passer%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0%2Csauter%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpasser%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csauter%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0), les 2 sont en effet quasi identiques en termes d'usage.

Il est tout à fait possible d'utiliser cette expression, et je pense que n'importe quel locuteur dont le français est la langue maternelle la comprendra. Cependant, « sauter/passer du coq à l'âne » reste une manière de parler plutôt soutenue (si besoin voici un rappel des [registres de langue](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registres_de_langue_en_fran%C3%A7ais)). Il est plus fréquent d'entendre une phrase du type :

> Excuse-moi, je change de sujet. Tu veux faire quoi ce soir ?

D'ailleurs, on remarque que « changer de sujet » tend à supplanter l'expression idiomatique « passer/sauter du coq à l'âne » : [source](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=passer+du+coq+%C3%A0%2Csauter+du+coq+%C3%A0%2Cje+change+de+sujet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpasser%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csauter%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20change%20de%20sujet%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpasser%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csauter%20du%20coq%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20change%20de%20sujet%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 4):

Oui. Il me semble que « **sauter** du coq à l'âne » est plus habituel mais les deux se disent encore couramment..